# cellForRowAtIndex customised method

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

In my `tableViewController` there is a `cellForRowAtIndex` method which has three possible sources.

1. Search results from a `search bar controller`.
2. Collapsed sections from `NSFetchedResultsController`.
3. Expanded sections from `NSFetchedResultsController`.

At the first option there are no issues.

At the second option, the method creates a new Top Row to announce that the section is expandable. No issues at this option.

At the third option, the selected section expands its rows, but with the issue that the first row is not the expected row, but the new Top Row from the previous option.

Here you have both screenshots:

[image][image]

And that is the method code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    // Configure the cell...
    
    ToDoItem *toDoItem = nil;
    
    //SEARCH RESULTS
    
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            
        }
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        toDoItem = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.todoName;
        
        
        
        NSDate *fechaToDO = toDoItem.todoDueDate;
        
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
        NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];
        
        NSString *valorSomeDay = toDoItem.isSomeDay;
        if ([valorSomeDay isEqualToString:@"issomeday"]){
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Someday";
        }
        else {
        
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;
        }
    }

    //COLLAPSABLE/EXPANDABLE
    else
    {
        if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
        {
            if (!indexPath.row)
            {
                // first row
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Expandable"; // only top row showing
                
                if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
                {
                    cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];
                }
            }
            else
                
                //FETCHED RESULTS
    
            {
        
                cell.accessoryView = nil;
                ToDoItem *todoitem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.textLabel.text = todoitem.todoName;
                
                
                
                NSDate *fechaToDO = todoitem.todoDueDate;
                
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
                NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];
                
                
                
                NSString *valorSomeDay = todoitem.isSomeDay;
                if ([valorSomeDay isEqualToString:@"issomeday"]){
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Someday";
                }
                else {
                    
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;
                }
       
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Any help is welcome to be able to show the first core data object and not the invented top row when expanding the sections.
It is also request to propose me another solution that could avoid the use of this invented top row when sections are collapsed..
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a mapping of your original index paths and the new index paths after you inserted the rows that resulted from the expansion.

If you implement it properly, you should be able to get the new index path from the old index path. Ex: item 3 is now 5 after row 1 was expanded and added 2 subrows.

EDIT: how to implement the mapping

You don't need to be experienced in iOS to implement it. I am not very experienced and I implemented it.

1. Create an array whose keys will be the index paths as the table view sees them (ie. 0 to 9 if you have 10 total rows), and the values are the index paths (or anything you want, really), that tell you what row in your datasource you are referencing (ie. 0, 1, 2, 3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4, 5, 6 if row 3 has 3 subrows currently expanded).
2. Whenever you expand (add) rows, insert them in that dictionary at the right place: in this example, when you expanded row 3, insert all 3 rows at index 4, 5, 6.
3. Whenever you collapse (remove) rows, delete them from that array.

Example:

```
0 => 0
1 => 1
2 => 2
3 => 3
4 => 4
5 => 5
6 => 6
```

becomes

```
0 => 0
1 => 1
2 => 2
3 => 3
4 => 3.0
5 => 3.1
6 => 3.2
7 => 4
8 => 5
9 => 6
```

when you expand row 3

Comment: Thank you, but would you mind showing me how to implement your proposal, I am not so experienced in iOS.

Comment: I guess that what you are proposing is to be coded at the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. If you have time, I could put my current code at that method on my question, may be you could take a look and tell me what should be changed there.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time. I have created and array, but as I am updating an existing tutorial code, the way to handle the rows and index path are completely different as you are proposing, and I am sure I can't change it in the way of your proposal. I will try to change the code by myself, and in the case I am not able to solve the issue, I will put another question. Thank you again.